# VBA SQL Query Displaying In Wrong Columns

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

I have a subroutine called `DoubleBookings` that queries 2 other Excel sheets and outputs the query to the DoubleBookings sheet. At the moment it's selecting the correct information but outputs half the info on the other-side of the sheet? Everything was working fine until I added the header. The other 4 sheets work fine but as this `select` statement is an `INNER JOIN` it's causing the issues shown in the images below.

```vb
Sub FindDoubleBookings()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.connection
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & _
    ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"";"
    
    Dim doubleQuery As String
    
    With Sheets("Inbounds")        
        Dim dataRef As String
        dataRef = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("8:" & .Rows.Count)).Address(0, 0)
        
        doubleQuery = "Select [vrid],[route],[schedule_date],[vehicle_carrier],[carrier_name],[orig_planned_yard_checkin_time],[orig_planned_yard_checkout_time],[dest_node]from [Inbounds$" & dataRef & "] AS Delivery INNER JOIN [Outbounds$" & dataRef & "] AS Collection on Delivery.actual_vehicle = Collection.actual_vehicle where Delivery.[orig_planned_yard_checkin_time] <= Collection.[orig_planned_yard_checkout_time] order by [Delivery.Route]"
    End With
    
    Dim drs As New ADODB.Recordset
    drs.Open doubleQuery, conn
    
    Dim wSht As Worksheet
    Set wSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DoubleBookings")
    
    With wSht
        .Cells.clearContents
        For i = 0 To drs.Fields.Count - 1
            .Cells(8, i + 1).Value = drs.Fields(i).Name
        Next i
        .Range("A9").CopyFromRecordset drs
    End With
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DoubleBookings").Activate
    conn.Close
End Sub
```

[image: Sheet after booking]

Comment: If I were to guess, I would say the merged cells at the top are the problem. If you take out the part that merges them, does it work as expected?

Comment: I removed the header and merged cells and it's still the same

Comment: I think the application.intersect is the issue and taking empty cells as well?

Comment: Using `*` in `SELECT *` could also be problematic.

Comment: What's the layout of `Outbounds` and `Inbounds`?  `SELECT *` returns all fields from both inner join tables. Is it your expected result?

Comment: Yes all records that match the where clause, it worked fine when I didn't have a header and I added the "Application.Intersect" to work around the header

Comment: When I run it in debug mode and hover over dataRef when it populates it is saying "A8:AN352" which is indicating that it is taking every row and column that is the same size as the header, is there a way to tell the "Application.Intersect" to skip the header

Comment: The result of `SELECT *` from `Outbounds$A8:AN352` joins with `Inbounds$A8:AN352` is 80 columns (each table has 40 columns). That's the reason why `outputs half the info on the other-side of the sheet`. I don't think it is related with skipping the header.

Comment: If I try to specify what columns to select I get "System Error &H80004005"

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code which raises the error.

Comment: Code updated with new Select statement that is giving error

Answer (score 0):

Changed the `Select` statement to the below and it works fine.

Thanks for the assistance.

```
 doubleQuery = "Select Delivery.[vrid],Delivery.[route],Delivery.[Schedule_date],Delivery.[vehicle_carrier],Delivery.[carrier_name],Delivery.[actual_vehicle],Delivery.[dest_planned_yard_checkin_time],Delivery.[dest_planned_yard_checkout_time]," & _
                          "Collection.[vrid],Collection.[route],Collection.[Schedule_date],Collection.[vehicle_carrier],Collection.[carrier_name],Collection.[actual_vehicle],Collection.[orig_planned_yard_checkin_time],Collection.[orig_planned_yard_checkout_time],Collection.[dest_node] from [Inbounds$" & dataRef & "] AS Delivery INNER JOIN [Outbounds$" & dataRef & "] AS Collection on Delivery.actual_vehicle = Collection.actual_vehicle where Delivery.[dest_planned_yard_checkin_time] >= Collection.[orig_planned_yard_checkout_time] order by [Delivery.Route]"
```